# Universal sentence encoder for the class similarity

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, multiclass-classification, sentence-similarity

I would like to create a similarity measurement on the class level for the AG-NEWS dataset ([dataset link](https://huggingface.co/datasets/ag_news)).
Since that dataset has four classes World (0), Sports (1), Business (2), Sci/Tech (3) I would like to get a 4x4 matrix with similarity measures between classes in this dataset.

I have seen a lot of examples regarding implementing a universal sentence encoder on sentence-level, like in this one: [basic example](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder). However, I could not find any example of the problem I would like to solve. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: I recommend using the `Doc2Vec` techniques to solve the problem!

Comment: @meti Hi, thank you. Why would Doc2Vec be a better solution than USE?

Comment: Using sentences as the unit of embeddings introduces new challenges to your workflow. In my opinion, there is a small chance that you are able to combine sentence embeddings in the optimal way to vectorize the whole document. But doc2vec architectures train to do so by utilizing hundreds of neurons.